# How To Hold Down a Button in Unity 5 C# For Mobile?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, mobile, uibutton

I am trying to make a simple game. I am trying to make it so when you hold down a UI button, an object will move. I want the object to stop moving when you let go of the button. It also needs to work on mobile. I could not find any tutorial that was thorough enough. It would be really helpful if you could explain. Thanks!

Comment: `OnPointerDown`. I will advice you to use the `Image` or `RawImage` component instead of button. Buttons are used to detect clicks.

Comment: @Programmer How would I implement that into the c#?

Comment: See the link from the duplicate. It has complete example for `OnPointerDown`